# .htaccess gives error while on RewriteEngine

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have .htaccess file in my main project folder and I want to remove .php extension from my pages in Url I wrote the .htaccess file as below.
[image: .htaccess file]

by the way it gives my the following error . I dont think my .htaccess configurations are wrong but still it doesn't work.

[image: my index file]

apache error logs 
[image]

Comment: Try it: `RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion bro but my apache error log content shows the above errors. I edited my questions and added the log error

Comment: You have to enable the a2enmod script in your ubuntu, use below code to unable this module:
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart